# Flutter Layout Inspector - "iOS" button missing

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

Looks like the "iOS" button was removed from Flutter Layout Inspector. How can I bring it back? It seems it was removed from the English docs, but is still present in other languages:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector
https://flutter-ko.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

[image]